# How to perform select group by with max in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, max

I have an object containing the following in PowerShell:

```
Date     Item Total
----     ---- -----
20190505 AAA   2
20190505 BBB   1
20190514 AAA   6
20190514 BBB   1
20190514 CCC   2
20190524 AAA   5
20190524 BBB   1
20190524 CCC   1
20190524 DDD   2
```

I want to select the maximum total for each type of item. The result should look something like this:

```
Item Total
---- -----
AAA   6
BBB   1
CCC   2
DDD   2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
$myObject | Group-Object -Property Item | Foreach {
    $_.Group | Sort Total -Descending | Select -First 1
}
```